# vue i18n issues: when i run my code, it tells that failed

Tags: vue.js

I encountered the following problem, when I tried to compile, I got the following error, can anyone help me!
[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCPPo.png)

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHmWD.png)

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my code :

    const lang = localStorage.lang;
    if (!lang) {
      lang = 'zh';
      localStorage.lang = lang;
    }

this is my error:
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                              10:49:28 AM

 error  in ./src/i18n/index.js

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Use object destructuring (prefer-destructuring) at src/i18n/index.js:6:7:
  4 | Vue.use(VueI18n);
  5 |
> 6 | const lang = localStorage.lang;
    |       ^
  7 | if (!lang) {
  8 |   lang = 'zh';
  9 |   localStorage.lang = lang;


error: 'lang' is constant (no-const-assign) at src/i18n/index.js:8:3:
   6 | const lang = localStorage.lang;
   7 | if (!lang) {
>  8 |   lang = 'zh';
   9 |   localStorage.lang = lang;
  10 | }
  11 | const req = require;
```